# Join eav attributes

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, products, eav, join

Im trying to join attributes in my collection on my grid view of "supply needs" from my ERP (Erp boost my shop)

The collection is loaded like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('Purchase/SupplyNeeds')->getCollection();
```

And then i tried to join it with catalog/product on product_id, which works fine, but it doesnt give me the attribute "product_class" that i want, because it tries to load it from purchase/supplyneeds.

I have joined it like this:

```
$collection->join('catalog/product', 'product_id=entity_id');
```

Which gives me a collection that looks like this for each product:

```
[product_id] => 8728
[manufacturer_id] => 570
[sku] => 18369
[name] => NEW - Tiny Teasers Opladelig Bullet Vibrator
[waiting_for_delivery_qty] => 0
[status] => 3_prefered_stock_level
[qty_min] => 0.0000
[qty_max] => 1.0000
[entity_id] => 8728
[entity_type_id] => 4
[attribute_set_id] => 17
[type_id] => simple
[has_options] => 0
[required_options] => 0
[created_at] => 2017-08-22 14:01:37
[updated_at] => 2017-08-22 14:04:17
[exclude_from_supply_needs] => 0
```

But how do i get my attribute product_class in my collection? a foreach takes too much time to load for 600 products

The getSQL looks like this with join statement:

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, `catalog/product`.* FROM `erp_view_supplyneeds_global` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `catalog/product` ON product_id=entity_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create main collection of product and join your table with it

```
 $collection =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
 $collection->join('Purchase/SupplyNeeds', 'product_id=entity_id');
 $collection->addAttributeToFilter("product_class",array('neq'=>''));
```

Or try Below code

```
 $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

 $coll = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('product_class',array('neq'=>''));
 $coll->getSelect()->join( array('supplyNeeds'=> $connection->getTableName('Purchase/SupplyNeeds')), 'supplyNeeds.product_id = e.entity_id', array('supplyNeeds.*' ) ); // here in last parameter pass all fields that you need from your table
```

Try above code and let me know

Comment: Sadly doesnt work. I just get a blank grid. Seems like its crashing at: $collection->join('Purchase/SupplyNeeds', 'product_id=entity_id');

Comment: @BrittanyMoore check updated code

Comment: I just updated my post. I think its getting near, but i get an error now. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: ahh I got it `array('supplyNeeds.created_at as ocreated' )` because of this code has issue replcae with field of your table, in array put all comma separted fields that you want in select or just do `array('supplyNeeds.* ')`

Comment: I updated the code please check

Comment: Hi. Updated my question again. Got a new error, dont really understand it. Thank you so much for your patience

Comment: print query and check in phpmyadmin

Comment: Hello again Murtuza. Thank you so much for trying to help me out. I have been trying to play a little around.. it seems like a conflict with name is happening, how could i resolve this? i have been running the command in phpmyadmin, see my updated question :)

Comment: Okay. Played a little more around with the code and got the SQL working. No more crashing. My problem now is that i get double entries

Comment: You can do groupby

Comment: My bad. Had changed to joinleft.. oops. Played around with some sorting and then it worked. 
The grid looks perfrect now.. until i start searching for something, then i get errors like `Invalid property name: manufacturer_id";i:1;s:2706:"#0 /var/www/app/code/local/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(1296): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Invalid prop...')` Does that make any sense to you? :/

Comment: Accepted your answer. Its working perfectly. I just need to play around with my searching to make it work. Thank you so much!

Comment: for filtering you need to use `filtercallback`

Comment: @BrittanyMoore you are always welcome :)

Comment: That `neq` is a nice little trick to force the attribute into the initial `JOIN` rather than loading it after the collection has loaded.

Comment: @KevinSchroeder, yes I faced this issue many times than I come with this solution